# Get the next value from database sequence

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpql

I have a sequence in database.
I need to get the incremented value.I wrote the query which supports only sql.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT nextval('sequence')", nativeQuery = true)
```

The Query is working fine.But i need to write the query to get the sequence number in JPQL(Which supports both SQL and oracle database)

Comment: I don't think that you can do that, as not all database systems supported by JPA have sequences.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have to support Oracle SQL, you can write:

```
SELECT sequence.nextval FROM dual
```

If you have to support multiple RDBMS, you'll need to either use a programmatically configured native query, or use something like [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) (disclaimer, I work for the vendor), or have one method per dialect with a `@Query` annotation on each, for example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT nextval('sequence')", nativeQuery = true)
int getPostgreSQLSequenceNextValue();

@Query(value = "SELECT sequence.nextval FROM dual", nativeQuery = true)
int getOracleSequenceNextValue();
```

This is a bit painful of course, but that's how annotations work.

Comment: Thankyou,How do i mention dialect in @Query?

Comment: @madhuri: You cannot mention the dialect in your `@Query`. I'll update my answer to show what I meant